# How to compare two objects by attribute using comparable - JAVA

Tags: java, comparable

I wish to compare two Die object by "int value" , and return the object with the higher value. What am I doing wrong ... Thanks

```
public class Die implements DieIntf , Comparable {

    private int value;

    public Die(){}

class ComparatorId implements Comparator<Die> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Die t, Die t1) {
               Integer d1 = t.getValue();
               Integer d2 = t.getValue();
               if(d1>d2) return 1;
               else if(d1<d2) return -1;
               else return 0;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: it looks like minor mistake, use Integer d2 = t1.getValue() not t.getValue()

Comment: Also, you haven't override compareTo(...) because of Comparable interface you have been implemented. can you make your code too clear rather than mess up all in one.

Answer (score 1):

> Do not use Comparable/Comparator interface, until you have any
>   requirement like sorting an object into ascending/descending order.
>
> In your case, you want Bigger Object(based upon it's value) return
>   while compare it.

*So do something likewise,*

```
public class Die{

    int value;


    public Die compareMyDieObjce(Die d){

        if(this.value > d.value){
            return this;
        }

        return d;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return " Object-Value : " + this.value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Die d1 = new Die(); d1.value = 5;
        Die d2 = new Die(); d2.value = 55;

        System.out.println(d1.compareMyDieObjce(d2)); // Object-Value : 55

    }

}
```